# HTTPS URL server certificate in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

How to get https server certificate using Net::HTTP or HTTPClient Ruby lib?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution using HTTPClient lib

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httpclient'

client = HTTPClient.new
response = client.get("https://gmail.google.com")
cert = response.peer_cert
```

Make sure you have httpclient gem installed

```
sudo gem install httpclient
```

Comment: You don't need `sudo` here. Always install gem's locally, not with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do it with either of these libraries, or even with much more advanced libcurl and it's wrappers. But as an alternative - if you have `openssl` command line tool available, you can invoke it and parse the output, the command you need is as follows:

`openssl s_client -connect my.server.name:443`

It will give you a full dump of the certificate as well as some parsed information - subject, issuer, etc.