# Parse X509 Certificate (and store information) with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I can parse an SSL cert from the CLI with the OpenSSL tools. I use this to query domains and SSL certs quickly without firing up a browser window. I'm playing around with RoR and would like to implement this as a web page function.

Reading up on the OpenSSL gem it has some parse features but doesn't look to be able to parse the data from an existing SSL cert and store it (in an array or file).

PHP can do this with the http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-parse.php function.

I've been reading different threads on SO and other places and most of the parsing seems to be for certs that I would create myself.

Any idea if this is doable in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting some help with some local Rubyists I discovered 2 different approaches to this problem.

The first approach is answered here on SO - [HTTPS URL server certificate in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954517/https-url-server-certificate-in-ruby). By using the `peer_client` option of `HTTPClient` you can get the encrypted certificate. Works as intended.

I then ran across this blog [post](http://findingscience.com/ruby/ssl/2013/01/13/reading-an-ssl-cert-in-ruby.html) and it uses the `OpenSSL` and `socket` approach. It also works quite well. I was able to read a websites SSL certificate, extract, and display the information I needed.

Here is the code snippet from the above blog post:

```
require 'socket'
require 'openssl'

tcp_client = TCPSocket.new("example.com", 443)
ssl_client = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(tcp_client)
ssl_client.connect
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(ssl_client.peer_cert)
ssl_client.sysclose
tcp_client.close

certprops = OpenSSL::X509::Name.new(cert.issuer).to_a
issuer = certprops.select { |name, data, type| name == "O" }.first[1]
results = { 
        :valid_on => cert.not_before,
        :valid_until => cert.not_after,
        :issuer => issuer,
        :valid => (ssl_client.verify_result == 0)
      }
```

Begs the question as to whether or not one is better than the other. I am not that deep of a Ruby dev to know as of now. I decided to go with the OpenSSL option and it is working well for my needs so far.